# Convert nested object Id to object when deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

*** Edit: Clarified there are two, separate JSON files ***

I have two classes:

```
public class Phone  
{
     public int PhoneId  { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Manufacturer PhoneManufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer  
{
    public int ManId  { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
}
```

And two JSON files containing data for both classes:

phones.json:

```json
[
   {
       "phoneId" : 45,
       "name": "S20",
       "phoneManufacturer":16
   }
]
```

manufacturers.json:

```json
[
   {
       "manId" : 16,
       "name": "Samsung"      
   }
]
```

I use the following code to deserialize the phones objects:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("phones.json");
return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Phone>>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true})!;
```

I want that when deserializing the Phones JSON to `List<Phone>`, the resulting objects will have its `PhoneManufacturer` property populated with the actual `Manufacturer` object.

When running the deserialization with the default parameters, I get an error that JSON cannot convert the value in the `PhoneManufacturer` property to a `Manufacturer` object, which makes sense since this is the object Id, and not the object itself.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: _the resulting objects will have its PhoneManufacturer property populated with the actual Manufacturer object._ I don't think you have a right json file.

Comment: What's the jsonString look like? Can you modify the JSON data to match the C sharp class structure?

Comment: Your JSON looks like not a correct/good format

Comment: I've edited the question to add clarity. There are two JSON files, and the jsonString variable stores the contents of the phone.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `System.Text.Json`, and you don't mind modifying the class to add a new constructor, this is quite achievable as long as you have a collection of manufacturers available to the `Phone` constructor.
Something like:

```
[JsonConstructor]
public Phone(int phoneId, string name, int phoneManufacturer)
{
    PhoneId = phoneId;
    Name = name;
    if(!ManufacturerDictionary.Contains(phoneManufacture)) throw new Exception();
    PhoneManufacturer = ManufacturerDictionary.[phoneManufacturer];
}
```

Comment: Oh, and load manufacturers.json first 

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a custom converter for manually mapping IDs to objects. There is a great series of Articles that cover this topic for both NewtonSoft & System.Text.Json: [Working with JSON Series](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1201466/Working-with-Newtonsoft-Json-in-Csharp-VB). The section labelled `Multi-Value Type Collections` is similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
var phonesJsonArr = JsonNode.Parse(phonesJson).AsArray();

var manufacturersJsonArr = JsonNode.Parse(manufacturersJson).AsArray();

    foreach (JsonNode node in phonesJsonArr)
    {
        var manId = node["phoneManufacturer"].GetValue<int>();
        node["PhoneManufacturer"] = new JsonObject
        {

            ["manId"] = manId,
            ["Name"] = manufacturersJsonArr.Where(ja => ja["manId"].GetValue<int>() == manId).Select(ja => ja["name"].GetValue<string>()).FirstOrDefault()

        };
         node.AsObject().Remove("phoneManufacturer");
     }

List<Phone> phones = phonesJsonArr.Deserialize<List<Phone>>(new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});
```